# issue with Qtwidgets

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2

I am just learning how to create GUI using Qtdesigner and Pycharm. so I build a really simple GUI with tow bottoms an a label. after compiling the .ui file in pycharm and writing this code to execute it:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from Algo_UI import untitled
class QtApp ( untitled.Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(QtApp, self).__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
  qt_app = QtApp()
  qt_app.show()
  app.exec_()
```

I got this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/al/0-Projects/Python/Algo/AlgoApp/Main.py", line 11, in <module>
qt_app = QtApp()
File "/home/al/0-Projects/Python/Algo/AlgoApp/Main.py", line 7, in __init__
self.setupUi(self)
File "/home/al/0-Projects/Python/Algo/AlgoApp/Algo_UI/untitled.py", line 17, in setupUi
self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
TypeError: QWidget(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = 
Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QtApp'
```

here is the first part of the Untitled.py file, where line-17 on the error massage refers to.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
   def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
```

how could I solve this Problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused because you should not combine PyQt5 with PySide2 as they can cause hard to debug errors. Although both classes use Qt they create different wrappers so a PyQt5 object cannot be used by a PySide2 object and vice versa. The solution is just to use a library, in this case change `from PySide2 import QtWidgets` to `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets`. Also change `app = QtWidgets.QApplication()` to `app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])`.